# How to count the number posts in a category

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to JavaScript, and I'm coding an Admin dashboard app, I have a page of categories (List), i want each category shows the number of posts.

What I've done is making a model for **`PostsCategory`**:

```
const PostsCategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },

        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },

        posts_Number: {
            type: Number,
        },

        catImage: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
        },

    },

    { timestamps: true }
);
```

I already have the **`Post`** model ready:

```
    const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
        {
            username: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            title: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            categories:{
                type: String,
                required: false,
            },
        },

 { timestamps: true }
);
```

Posts Routes:

```
//CREATE POST
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const newPost = new Post(req.body);
    try {
        const savedPost = await newPost.save();
        res.status(200).json(savedPost);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
        console.log(err);
    }
  });
```

What i'm trying to do here is when a post is created the `posts_Number` in `PostsCategorySchema` should increase by 1, then I would call this to my frontend showing the number of posts the category has. I'm not sure if its the right way to do this or there is an easy way I don't know about.

Comment: Are there multiple categories? And you are trying to count the number of posts in each category?

Comment: 1) One I can understand is you are looking to have a Unique Number ID with Auto-Incremental - for that you can use either random ID / Number Generation 
i.e.  - Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000)

or 2)  You need to fetch the last number from DB (MAX - POST_NUMBER) +1 to generate an incrementing number / ID

3) You can keep in DB field constraints / auto-increment IDENTITY column

Comment: Yes they are a multiple categories, and when creating a post I should choose one of the categories

Answer (score 0):

in PostsCategory

- add

```
PostsCategorySchema.virtual('postCount', {
 ref: 'User', // collection name this field references
 localField: '_id', // the ID to of this story
 foreignField: 'categories', // the field on the Story document to match with the ID
 count: true, // only return a count of documents
});
```

- while find make populate
- for example

  ```
  const promotions = await YOUR_MODEL.find()
     .populate("postCount");
  ```